# PORTB Interrupt On Change changes state unintentionally

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts

I am running below code in a PIC16F887 that runs at 20 MHz. I feed `PORTB.0` a signal of 1 KHz from my signal generator. However, whenever the signal is low, `PORTC.1` toggles at a rate of either ~5usec or ~10usec.  Also, I've connected an OP-AMP's output that gives 0V-4V, still the same.

I have tried enabling weak pull ups inside, didn't work.

The microcontroller is on an [EasyPIC5](http://www.mikroe.com/eng/products/view/1/easypic5-development-system/) development board, so I can enable and disable either pull-up or pull-down resistors that are 10K. Didn't work, either.

Is this some kind of silicon problem(?) or is there a mistake in my code?

Here is a screenshot from the oscilloscope that probes `PORTC.1`:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code, please omit off-topic part of it:

```
volatile unsigned int fiftymicros=0;
volatile unsigned int milis=0;
volatile unsigned char fiftymicroscounter=0;
volatile unsigned int data_time=0;
volatile unsigned int milis_ctr=0;
unsigned long int data_bar[20]={0};
void interrupt()
{
     if(INTCON.T0IF)
     {
      TMR0=198;
      INTCON.T0IF=0;
      fiftymicros++;
      if(++fiftymicroscounter==40) { fiftymicroscounter=0; milis++; }
     }
     if(INTCON.RBIF)
     {
      PORTC.F1=~PORTC.F1;
      INTCON.RBIF=0;
     }
}
void main()
{
     ANSEL =0;
     ANSELH=0;
     TRISA=0; PORTA=0;
     TRISB=0x01; PORTB=0;
     TRISC=0; PORTC=0;
     TRISD=0; PORTD=0;
     TRISE=0; PORTE=0;
     OPTION_REG.INTEDG=1;
     OPTION_REG.T0CS=0;
     OPTION_REG.PSA=0;
     OPTION_REG.PS0=1;
     OPTION_REG.PS1=0;
     OPTION_REG.PS2=0;
     //OPTION_REG.B7=0;
     //WPUB=0x80;
     INTCON.TMR0IE=0;
     INTCON.RBIE=1;
     IOCB.B0=1;
     INTCON.GIE=1;
     UART1_Init(9600);
     Delay_ms(100);
     milis_ctr=milis;
     while(1)
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: You are probably not clearing the condition properly on the high to low transition, so it keep recurring.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I guess me blaming hardware prevented you from writing an answer :) `...silicon problem...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read PORTB before clearing the RBIF flag inside interrupt(), otherwise the mismatch will still exist and the RBIF flag won't be cleared.  See section 3.4.3 INTERRUPT-ON-CHANGE in the PIC's datasheet:

> For enabled interrupt-on-change pins, the present value is compared
>   with the old value latched on the **last read of PORTB** to determine
>   which bits have changed or mismatched the old value.

Comment: I wonder why those application notes do not include C code. I am not against assembly, however, they should include both. [AN566](http://goo.gl/jSHlm) supports this answer. `EXAMPLE 1: SINGLE INTERRUPT WITH A SMALL PULSE ...
CLR_RBINTF MOVF PORTB, 1 ; Read PortB (to itself) to end
; mismatch condition`